# How to make login for 10 type of users in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-authentication, laravel-authorization

I am making a login for 10 types of users. for Example .. `Admin, Cutting Company, Packaging Company, Truck, Boss` and more like that. I was thinking about roles and permissions. But I am not sure how I will handle that. Because all type of users has the different king of fields (database columns). And half of the users will be connected through the app. so I will need to create APIs for those users.

So My question is here that I should create 10 Login pages for every type of user? Or I should go for roles and permissions. or Is there any other option is also available.

Is there any package available?

Comment: Roles/permissions, store the user stuff - name, email, password - in the users table, and the role-specific stuff in different tables. A user may *have* a truck; they are not a truck.

Comment: [Access-control list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list) aka ACL is the way to go, For users with different fields you can create user table for common attributes and meta table with one to one relation for different attributes or you can use [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) with one to many